# Data from pivot table through joins laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

Hi I'm trying to display the project names through my pivot table called tagprojects. Unfortunately I can't realize it. I will show you what I have tried. First I will show you my controller called ProjectController.php:

```
public function get_results($keyword){

    $projects=Project::search2($keyword);
    //die(print_r($tagprojects));

    return View::make('user.projects.results')->with('project', 'Offertes - Zoek resultaten')
    ->with('projects', $projects);
}
```

The search2() method is defined in my model called Project.php:

```
public static function search2($keyword){
    //return static::DB::table('tagprojects')
    $keyword='ta';
    $result=DB::table('tagprojects')
        ->join('projects', 'tagprojects.id_project', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('tags', 'tagprojects.id_tag', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->where('tags.tag_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();

    /*
    $result=DB::table('tagprojects')
        ->join('projects', 'tagprojects.id_project', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('tags', 'tagprojects.id_tag', '=', 'tags.id')
        ->select( 'projects.project_name')
        ->where('projects.project_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')
        ->where('tags.tag_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
     */ 
        //->paginate(3);
        //->get();
    return $result;

}
```

And here is my view called results.blade.php:

```
@foreach ($projects as $tp)
    <li>
    {{$tp->id_tag}}
    {{--    {{$tp->project['project_name']}} --}}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Well {{$tp->id_tag}} works but I actually want to see the project names. And as you can see in my code I already have tried {{$tp->project['project_name']}}. Unfortunately that didn't work, because then I get the following error:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$project (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\offerteTool\app\views\user\projects\results.blade.php)
```

I also have tried {{$tp->project->project_name}} but then I also receive the same error. But then I had tried {{die(print_r($projects))}} and the output was:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [id_tag] => 6 [id_project] => 3 [project_name] => Velma [project_description] => Dormouse! Turn that Dormouse out of sight; and an Eaglet, and several other curious creatures. Alice led the way, was the first day,' said the Caterpillar. Alice folded her hands, and began:-- 'You. [hour] => 96 [created_at] => 2014-10-16 08:52:08 [updated_at] => 2014-10-16 08:52:08 [tag_name] => accountancy ) ) 1
```

As you can see the output shows the column project_name, but for some reason I can't display project_name column. Can someone help me, please? Gladly I'm waiting for your response. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your relevant projects like this:

```
$projects = Project::with('tags')->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($keyword) {
    $q->where('tag_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
});
```

You can loop through the projects and fetch your tags as normal. I assume that would be done like this

```
foreach($projects as $project) {
    $tags = $project->tags;
}
```

Additionally if you just want to eager load the tags that you are matching:

```
$projects = Project::with(['tags' => function($q) {
    $q->where('tag_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}])->whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($keyword) {
    $q->where('tag_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
});
```

There might be a better method of doing that last part, but I have never come across the need for logic like that before.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this. I don't use the get_results() method anymore. Because now I only use the post_search() method in my controller:

```
public function post_search()
{

    $keyword=Input::get('keyword');

    if(empty($keyword))
        return Redirect::route('user.projects.index')->with('message', 'No keyword entered, please try again');

    $projects=Project::search3($keyword);

    foreach( $projects as &$project){

        //we initialize projecttask
        $project->projecttask = Projecttask::where('id_project', '=', $project->id)->get();

    };

    //die(print_r($projects));

    return View::make('user.projects.index', compact('projects'));

}
```

And now I use a method called search3(), which is defined in my model called Project.php (I still haven't escaped this query yet against SQL injection):

```
public static function search3($keyword){

    $result = DB::Select(DB::raw('SELECT projects.*, tagx.tags_all 
        FROM projects LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name SEPARATOR ",") 
            AS tags_all, tagprojects.id_project FROM tags JOIN tagprojects 
            on tagprojects.id_tag = tags.id GROUP BY tagprojects.id_project) as tagx 
            ON tagx.id_project = projects.id WHERE projects.project_name 
            LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%" OR tags_all LIKE "%'.$keyword.'%"'));

    return $result;


}
```